# Links rendered incorrectly

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks

I just posted an answer to a question: [Codeigniter not displaying stylsheet when clicking on links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894081/codeigniter-not-displaying-stylsheet-when-clicking-on-links/17894752#17894752)

I used example links that seems to have rendered really badly, with half-generated HTML anchors...

Any idea what could have caused that?

Comment: Well, the underscores caused it. That's not very helpful, though, I know. As a workaround, wrap the illustrative URLs with backticks, like this: `http://domain.tld/index.php/_/css/style.css`

Comment: You should probably use backslashes in most cases, willy nilly throwing back ticks in makes things hard to read.

Comment: I see, thanks. (And I do apologise - I'm using Opera Mini for my morning question-answering - so I can't seem to search for similar issues. Sometimes it searches, other times it doesn't...)

Comment: Has it ever been suggested that SO should automatically determine what links are examples, and backtick them automagically?

Comment: I don't think so (could be wrong), but how would that work? Anything that is a broken/invalid link would be backtick-escaped?

Comment: Yeah, but more on the domain/DNS side of things... It would need to ignore 404s as a user may need to demonstrate something on a 404 page. But where any domain that doesn't exist, the entire link should be back-ticked.